# Anonymous Classes, When and Where?

Tags: java, class, anonymous

I am teaching myself java, and I am really enjoying it, however I have come to the "Anonymous Class" subject, and I am trying to understand when, and where you would even use this, from what my book says it is a very popular class, but I can't seem to get my head around it, I understand how to create them. but i was just looking for a bit more information, so i can start implementing them in my classes.

I would really appreciate some examples, and a bit more explanation on when it would be useful to use them.

Comment: I generally avoid them like the plague TBH, unless I'm trying to write some simple classes just to test something. They're not needed in any sense. In a full production environment, they are generally not needed or desirable and simply complicate code unnecessarily. It is far cleaner to simply write discreet classes in discreet files and allows for division of work/concerns. But, some people may find greater use for them. I think they're near useless, except for very basic testing purposes or very small discreet anonymous classes of only a few lines that implement, say, ActionListener, etc.

Comment: I suggest you read the code in the collections libraries under java.util.  This has plenty of examples. I also suggest you read all the classes in java.lang.  You would be amazed how many people haven't read the source of even the most common libraries. ;)

Comment: I would say that in Java 8, for most intents and purposes, the anonymous class has been replaced by the lambda expression.  Understanding anonymous classes remains important for reading and maintaining legacy code.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I find when learning from a book you are restricted to just what is on the page, and you cannot ask any questions, so I really appreciate you all giving your input, and helping me understand, I don't like being a nuisance but i also dont want to walk into a job with a bleak understanding.. I would much rather learn as much as possible.. Thank you for all of your help again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you never *need* an anonymous class. You can always create a named class. When you're starting out, the main reason to learn about anonymous classes is to recognize them in code you read.

You use an anonymous class in cases where you want to create some object to use it only once (so it's not worthwhile to give a name to the type, put it in its own file, etc.). Mostly they come in handy in event-driven programming, such as using Swing. Your event handler is typically a one-off that is specific to the control you're plugging it into, so there's no point giving it a name.

For event handlers it's common to need access to the surrounding object, so it's convenient for the event handler to be an inner class, and its references to the surrounding context mean it's not reusable at all.

Good starting examples are in [the Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). The classes FileFilter and FilenameFilter in the java.io package are often used with anonymous classes to specify what files the filter should return.

In Java 8 [lambdas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) give you a better way to create single-use instances of classes with only one method.

Comment: Very nice post +1.  Often, particularly in event-driven code, even though an anonymous class is written once, an instance of it is created once per event or call and then discarded.  In such a case, better resource utilization will be obtained by assigning the anonymous class to a static constant or to an enum or by using a named class and using that instead of instantiating the anonymous class over and over again.

Comment: @scottb: i can't think of an example of that offhand, but yes, assigning the anonymous instance to a constant is certainly ok.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, although i feel like a nuisance by asking simple questions like this I would like to learn as much as possible so when I apply for a job within java I can adapt and learn while on the job, so i really appreciate your input and giving me links, it has really helped,

Answer (score 0):

If you write a named class `SomeClass`, then realise you only need to write `new SomeClass` once, it often makes more sense to use an anonymous class instead.

You should only do this if the body of the class is short (otherwise readability suffers) and if you couldn't use a lambda or method reference instead.

Comment: *"then realise you only need to write new SomeClass once"* ... do we *ever* write the same class more than once?

Comment: @scottb I'm not talking about writing the same class only once, I'm talking about only invoking the constructor in one place.